# In which Batman comic issue was there a plague of illiteracy?

Tags: story-identification, dc, batman, episode-identification

I read this one on paper so it was likely pre-2004, possibly pre-2000.

Not sure which villain was the perpetrator -- maybe the Joker? -- but I seem to recall it being caused by a hand-sized, horn-shaped device hooked into the innards of TV sets, which were possibly sold to unsuspecting citizens by henchmen.

I do recall one scene in the comic where EMT responders cannot read their pill bottles to administer drugs to an old lady who has collapsed, so Batman has to help them, as he is unaffected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about [Riot Act](http://www.comicvine.com/the-batman-adventures-4-riot-act/4000-36711/) and [Riot Act II](http://www.comicvine.com/the-batman-adventures-5-riot-act-ii/4000-36817/) - Issues #4 & 5 from Jan & Feb 1993. From Comic Vine:

> Someone [the Scarecrow] has thrown Gotham City into utter chaos by stealing ... Are you ready? Everyones literacy.  Thankfully Batman and Robin are on the case. Yet while stopping the riots and looting they find they have little time to figure out how everyones ability to read has been stolen from them.

Comment: Ah, yes -- I recognize the cover of Riot Act II, and the fact that the Scarecrow was the villian.  Thanks!

Comment: Was this comic perhaps a comic-ization of a Batman: The Animated Series episode, or vice versa? I can't find mention of a B:TAS episode with the name "Riot Act," but the plot seems familiar, even though I didn't read the comic books from that era.

Comment: @GarrettAlbright: Yes, it appears that [the comics were a spinoff from the animated series](http://www.comicvine.com/the-batman-adventures/4050-4716/) -- the art is certainly the same.